# Why my logger info its not working on service classes, but in controller it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Im trying to debug a applications of mine.

On my controller, everything looks fine.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  rescue_from PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError do |e|
    redirect_to root_path, alert: e.message
  end
 def change_plan
    logger.info('Changing the Plan')
```

But when I try to do the same thing in my services folder:

```
class PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionService < PaymentGateway::Service
  ERROR_MESSAGE = "There was an error while creating the subscription"
  attr_accessor :user, :plan, :token, :subscription, :success

def run
 logger.info('Starting the PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionService.run')
    begin
      Subscription.transaction do
        create_client_subscription
        self.subscription = create_subscription
        self.success = true
      end
    rescue PaymentGateway::CreateCustomerService, 
      PaymentGateway::CreatePlanService,
      PaymentGateway::ClientError => e
      raise PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionServiceError,e.message

    end
  end
```

I get an error:

```
undefined local variable or method `logger' for #<PaymentGateway::CreateSubscriptionService:0x007f2f4eaff788>
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a method called `logger` available on all the controllers.

```
def logger
  ActionController::Base.logger
end
```

You can add one to your classes or just use `Rails.logger` instead of `logger`.

```
def logger
  Rails.logger
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the logger isn't being initialised in your services folder.

I think that if you initialise the logger in your services folder then it should work.

Try this: `logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`